# how to Upgrade Java version of current project in linux?

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, java-8

currently my project is running on linux server which complied in jdk5 now i want change jdk version jdk5 to jdk8 so for that what can i do?

I applied these steps: 
1) Doc base deployment i followed so i change in apache2.27/conf/httpd_vhost.conf file and worker.properties as per as my latest complied(JDK8) location directory.

httpd_vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin 
 DocumentRoot /usr/local/ProjectJ8/demoregserver
 ServerName  
 DirectoryIndex      index.html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/usr/local/apache2.2.27/cgi-bin/"
    Alias /demoregserver "/usr/local/ProjectJ8/demoregserver"
 <Directory "/usr/local/ProjectJ8/demoregserver">
     Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
            <Location "/demoregserver/WEB-INF/">
            </Location>

            <Location "/demoregserver/META-INF/">
            </Location>

JkMount /demoregserver/servlet/* wsworker
JkMount /demoregserver/*.jsp wsworker
JkMount /demoregserver/kaptcha.jpg wsworker

 #AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

   # RewriteEngine   On
   # RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
   # RewriteLogLevel 10

   # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .rpm
   # RewriteCond ${tokenize:%{REMOTE_ADDR}%{QUERY_STRING}} !^$
   # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?${tokenize:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} [R,L]


CustomLog           demoregserver_access_log common
CustomLog           demoregserver_referer_log referer
CustomLog           demoregserver_agent_log agent
```

2) I also changed tomcate/conf/server.xml and workder.properties. in worker.properties change java_home=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_101

server.xml:

```
<Context path="/demoregserver"
                    docBase="/usr/local/ProjectJ8/demoregserver"
                    debug="0"
                    crossContext="false" >
            </Context>
```

I am calling this project using specific Url from different project and getting this error:

```
    Exception while getting Registration Response java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://update.demoreg.com/demoregserver/servlet/CustomerMyAccountManager
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://update.demoreg.com/demoregserver/servlet/CustomerMyAccountManager
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
            at registration.helpers.DemoRegProcess.registration(DemoRegProcess.java:150)
            at registration.helpers.DemoRegProcess.subscription(DemoRegProcess.java:47)
            at registration.helpers.SubscriptionHelper.processSubscription(SubscriptionHelper.java:219)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.filter.RequestFilterServlet.doFilter(RequestFilterServlet.java:60)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
            at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
            at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
            at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
            at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this about the error 500:

> HTTP Error 500 Internal server error
>   Introduction

The Web server (running the Web Site) encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) for access to the requested URL.

This is a 'catch-all' error generated by the Web server. Basically something has gone wrong, but the server can not be more specific about the error condition in its response to the client. In addition to the 500 error notified back to the client, the Web server should generate some kind of internal error log which gives more details of what went wrong. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse these logs. (Last updated: October 2013)
Fixing 500 errors - general

This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

Comment: so i need any further changes for run application using jdk8.? thanks for information about HTTP 500 Error. i saw in logs it gives internal server eroor but i could not found exact problem.